# PowerShell Table column to string delimited with ','

Tags: string, powershell, hashtable

I am trying to convert values under 'key' column to a single string delimited with ','

```
$TheTable = (get-command get-mailbox).Parameters
```

Command returns:

```
Key                    Value                                         
---                    -----                                         
ErrorAction            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
IncludeInactiveMailbox System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
Verbose                System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
OutVariable            System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata
```

I am trying to achieve:

```
$TheTable = "ErrorAction,IncludeInactiveMailbox,Verbose,OutVariable"
```

I am completely lost as everything I attempt (foreach loop, .ToString) returns:

```
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Management.Automation.ParameterMetadata],
```

Is there any way too do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- To get a hashtable's / dictionary's keys, use its `.Keys` property.
- To convert a collection of strings to a single string with a separator, use the `-join` operator.

Therefore:

```
$TheTable = (get-command get-mailbox).Parameters.Keys -join ","
```